# Jquery how to add attribute to father object?

Tags: jquery, css, function, class, checkbox

So here's the situation

I have this jquery code

```
$("li").click(function(){
var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( checkbox.prop("checked") == "" ){
        checkbox.prop("checked", true);
        (this).addClass("on");
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked", false);
        ("li").removeClass("on");
    }
});
```

And this html

```
<ul id="id_priori">
<li><label for="id_priori_0"><input id="id_priori_0" name="priori" type="checkbox"> Hola</label></li>
</ul>
```

What i want to do is add / remove the class on the

depending on if the checkbox is checked or unchecked , but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this to just

```
$("li").click(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        checkbox = self.find("input[type='checkbox']")[0];

    // change the checkbox state
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;

    self.toggleClass( 'on', checkbox.checked );
});
```

---

End even better to delegate the handler to just the `ul`

```
$("#id_priori").on('click', 'li', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        checkbox = self.find("input[type='checkbox']")[0];

    // change the checkbox state
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;

    self.toggleClass( 'on', checkbox.checked );
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/W9D8n/2/

---

**Update**

To make the prechecked `li` element to have the `on` class add

```
.find(":checkbox").each(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('on', this.checked);
});
```

to the code.

```
$("#id_priori").on('click', 'li', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        checkbox = self.find(":checkbox")[0];

    // change the checkbox state
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;

    self.toggleClass( 'on', checkbox.checked );

}).find(":checkbox").each(function(){

    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('on', this.checked);

});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/W9D8n/3/

Comment: @Maks notice the `[0]` at the end of the checkbox line; This will extract the DOM element out of the jquery object, so you can access its `checked` property.

Comment: Right but the problem is that when i click the li its checks and unchecks the checkboxs , not the label , so that code doesnt work :/

Comment: Now it works :) but i am having the same problem as above , when i send the form and it has an error the li's whose checkboxs are checked doesnt have the class "on"

Comment: @maks, added update to handle that case. (*but to be honest, that should probably be handled server-side when rendering the html*)

Comment: Sorry , but I need your help again , so can I do the same but with radiobuttons I want that when you click another radio button the one selected before removes the class "on"

Answer (score 1):

**Couple mistakes:**

**Change:**

```
("li").removeClass("on");
```

**To:**

```
$("li").removeClass("on"); // You are missing the $
```

**Change:**

```
(this).addClass("on");
```

**To:**

```
$(this).addClass("on"); // You are missing the $
```

Also, use `.is(:checked')` to see if the checkbox is checked.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').addClass('on');
    $("li").click(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            $(this).addClass("on");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("on");
        }
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9FWmf/1)**

Comment: It worked :D , but i need something else , when u reload the page , if the checkbox is clicked i want the li to have the class , how can i do it ?

Comment: Updated answer :) I added `checked` into the `input` in `html` so it is checked on page load. Also used `addClass` on the `ready` function

Comment: Yes i am trying to tweak it a bit because for some reason they all have the attribute even the ones that arent checked

Comment: It seems like when i send the form it doesnt run the jquery code, any idea ?

Comment: Sure :) http://jsfiddle.net/9FWmf/5/ , Send the form , go back and you'll see what i am talking about

Comment: Dont worry :) thanks for the help , he already did it above :)